# Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) and Nonnegative Matrix Factorization (NMF) as dimensionality reduction techniques

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, svd, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I am reading about SVD and NMF and how they can be used for dimensionality reduction of a data matrix X
. What I did not understand why the data matrix is still have the same dimensions after SVD or NMF approximation? For example, if X
is 6x5 matrix, the result is still 6x5 matrix but it has a lower rank approximation. Does having a lower rank here means reducing the dimensions?

The situation is clear for me in the case of principal component analysis where we can reduce the data matrix for say 6x3 matrix (keeping only the first three components).

Please explain what I am missing.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of rank in linear algebra?